# Proof that $n!\le 4(n/2)^{n+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

I am going through a book on Analysis and have to prove that $$n!\le 4(n/2)^{n+1}$$ using Bernoulli's inequality $(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh $ for $h>-1$ and induction.
I am not sure where to start here. But I tried the following.
We are given the inequality $n!\le 4(n/2)^{n+1}$ Inside the bracket I can add and subtract 1 to get: $n!\le 4(1+n/2-1)^{n+1}$ Since $n>0$ $n/2-1\ge -1$ and therefore I can use the Bernoulli inequality to write the right hand side as: $4(1+(n/2-1)(n+1))$ whic can be simplified further to $4(1+1/2(n+1)(n-1))$
Well I am not sure how to proceed from here, because I can't use the Bernoulli's inequality here to use it as an upper bound for the LHS of the statement to be proven.

Comment: The lower bound on h is inclusive, i.e. $(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh $ for $h \ge -1$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, well the question in the book says by induction. But I'd be interested in other proofs as well, however I can't accept it as the answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use induction. Clearly true for $n=1$. Assume that

$n!\leq\,4(\dfrac{n}{2})^{n+1}$, and multily both sides by $n+1$. We get

$(n+1)!\,\leq\,4(\dfrac{n}{2})^{n+1}.(n+1).$

Now all we need is to prove:

$4(\dfrac{n}{2})^{n+1}.(n+1)\leq4(\dfrac{n+1}{2})^{n+2}$. Simplifying we get :

$2n^{n+1}\,\leq\,(n+1)^{n+1}$, which is equivalent to:

$2\,\leq\,(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^{n+1}$. But $(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^{n}$ is an increasing sequence so it is always greater or equal

than the first term which is $2$. Thus $(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n\,\geq\,2$

and clearly $(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^{n}(1+\dfrac{1}{n})\,\geq\,2$ and we are done!!

Comment: Nice, +1.  Alternately for the last bit, Bernoulli's inequality gives $$\left( 1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1} \geqslant 2+\frac1n$$

Comment: Absolutely right!